# Error opening report with a crosstab query

Tags: crosstab

I'm trying to open a report from a form, the report opens good when iI test it in MS Access but when I run it from my form (see the code below), it says

> Run-time error '3070' the Microsoft Office Access database engine not recognize" as a valid field name or expression.

```
If Me.Check70.Value = True Then
DoCmd.OpenQuery "INTERMEDIATESYSTEM_CROSSTAB"
DoCmd.OpenReport "INTERMEDIATESYSTEM_Crosstab", acViewPreview
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "INTERMEDIATESYSTEM_CROSSTAB"
Application.DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, "INTERMEDIATESYSTEM_CROSSTAB"
DoCmd.Maximize
'DoCmd.Close acForm, "QBF_EDITFORM"
Exit Sub
End If
```

Like I said the cross tab query works good and the report works good but when I run it from the form it gives me an error.